# how to move a gazebo object with rosserial_arduino values from flex sensor

Tags: arduino, gazebo, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi...

i have a haptic glove with 5 flex (one per finger) sensors that send the information of his values to ros with an arduino mega 2560 by rosserial, that values are publicated in topics (5 topics, one per flex sensor) a nodes are subscripted to  each topic and publicated the sensors information, now  i need to use that values in gazebo to move an object made in a urdf file, the object is a hand with 15 joints 3 per finger, anyone knows how can i do that???

thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48290/how-to-move-a-gazebo-object-with-rosserial_arduino-values-from-flex-sensor/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-14**:
Please be more specific and always tag your questions to make sure the right people find it. What sensor are you using, i.e. what's the data you are getting? Absolute positions? Forces? Encoder values? Make sure you have a look at http://ros.org/wiki/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, there is no direct way to set joint positions in Gazebo. However, you can apply a force/effort at a joint for a specific duration and move the connected links that way. Have a look at Gazebo's apply_joint_effort. To move the joint to a specific position, you'll have to implement a position controller.

Alternatively, you can implement a gazebo plugin that controls your joints directly, something similar to the [gazebo_controller_manager](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_gazebo_plugins#gazebo_controller_manager). Maybe you can even use it.

A third alternative is to compute the link poses of your simulated hand manually using forward kinematics and just set the resulting link poses in gazebo. The joint values should be updated automatically ([related post](http://www.ode.org/old_list_archives/2006-June/019276.html)).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1